# Is there a way to set the yaxis tickmode=array in a plotly figure factory annotated heatmap?

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap

I'm trying to make a heatmap with annotated text using plotly and am having trouble displaying the y-axis values on the heatmap since the y-axis is divided into array intervals. I tried to set the yaxis tickmode to array using go.Layout like this:

```
fig4=ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z=Dens_Mean_A[::-1], annotated_text=text)
fig4.layout.update(go.Layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=300,
    height=500,
    yaxis=dict(
        tickmode='array',
        tickvals=np.subtract(np.arange(len(edge_A[0])), 0.5)
    ),
    xaxis=dict(
        showticklabels=False
    )
))
```

My heatmap does not show the yticks. Any other solutions?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve). In particular add a sample of your data.

Comment: I recently answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62475644/4819376) if that could help consider to flag this question as duplicate.

Comment: It doesn't work in my code unfortunately, but i understand the reference. Thanks.

Comment: If you can produce a [mcve](/help/mcve) we could try to better help you.